# how to damage copies of 1 enemy with

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have trouble with damaging system.
I have made a damage system using property(animation property to damage at specific frame) and ray detecting "dmg" property connected to enemy object hp removal actuator with enemy having "dmg" property.
When i test on 1 (original) enemy, it works but when i want to make enemies appear via add object actuator it causes only the original object take damage.i tried to put the original on other layer but still didnt do anything. any idea how to make it work?

[image: the system]

would also accept a new system for damage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have solved it by myself by learning python and making new system, using this script. anyway thx for  answers...

```
from bge import logic as GameLogic
c = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
own = c.owner

enemydetect = c.sensors["enemydetect"]
punchright = c.sensors["punchright"]
if punchright.positive and enemydetect.positive:


    obj = enemydetect.hitObject

    obj["HP"] = obj["HP"] - own["RightDamage"]
```